# OpenJFX software site has no categorized items

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4, target-platform, efxclipse

I would like to add JavaFX to my e4 application. I've been following [this tutorial](http://blog.vogella.com/2019/11/15/add-javafx-controls-to-a-swt-eclipse-4-application-eclipse-rcp-cookbook-update/) to get it working with Java 11.

The tutorial says to add this software site: http://downloads.efxclipse.bestsolution.at/p2-repos/openjfx-11/repository/

When I add this it says there are no categorized items so I can't install any plugins from here.

Is there an alternative I should be using or is there a bug in the software site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deselect the 'group items by category' check box on the install dialog to see uncategorized items.
[image: Install dialog]